# Make one button trigger another button's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When I click button A, a function gets called. If that function returns a certain value, I want to trigger the click event on button B, which will call its own function.

I tried `angular.element('#secondbutton').trigger(click)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: can u write any sample

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question got flagged for improvement, so I fixed the tags (`trigger` is more related to SQL) and clarified the wording. When you ask another question, it would be helpful to include the relevant parts of the code you're working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to use `ng-click` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick))

```
<button ng-click="doSomething()">Submit</button>
<button ng-click="secondFx()" id="btnTwo">Button Two</button>
```

in your controller you can define the functions that you bind to your html buttons

```
$scope.secondFx = function() { 
  // your logic here
  angular.element('#btnTwo').click();
};

$scope.doSomething = function() {
 // trigger second function 
 $scope.secondFx();
}
```

Comment: the problem is when the second button click i need to use jquery to do the thing i want to do.

Comment: in `secondFx` you can use jquery. `$(#'myBtn').click()`

Comment: @BaoyunChen, you have to bind click event from here and then trigger.

Comment: @user2954587, You should not use any html($('#btnTwo').click()) element into controller, write directive.

Comment: @user2954587 Thanks, it works, but instead of  $('#btnTwo').click() i need to use angular.element('#showrpt').click();